# Math Order of Operations Error AngularJS with Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been using `Ionic Framework` for about 4 months or so and am still learning the ropes to `AngularJS`.  I'm trying to have `Angular` perform a calculation but it will not compute the correct way (does not appear to follow order of operations). The info binds fine between `Angular` and `HTL` because I've done several other calculations with this app I'm making.  Here's what I got:

```
.controller('CalcCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    //Initial Strike Water Requirements
    $scope.startingWater = "";
    $scope.lbsOfGrain = "";
    $scope.grainTemp = "";
    $scope.targetTemp = "";
    $scope.iniStrikeCalc = function(){
        $scope.r = $scope.startingWater/(4*$scope.lbsOfGrain);
        $scope.iStrikeResult = (.2/$scope.r)*($scope.targetTemp-$scope.grainTemp)+$scope.targetTemp;
    };
}])
```

I input the following values:

`startingWater = 5`

`lbsOfGrain = 10`

`grainTemp = 70`

`targetTemp = 155`


The actual answer **should** be 163.5

The ionic calculated answer is 8.5


When I analyzed the `iStrikeResult` formula, it appeared to me that the last term,  **+ $scope.targetTemp**  was not factored into the end of the equation.  I don't know why this is happening.


Also, any good resources (books??) for learning the intricacies of Angular would be appreciated.  I've worked through several courses on codecademy and that has helped much.

Please forgive any forum etiquette I may break.  This is my first post.

Here is the html I'm using

```
<div class="list card">
    <div class="item stable-bg">
        <h2 align="center">Initial Strike Water Calculator</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body" align="left" ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label"><b>Initial Gallons of Water</b></span>
            <input type="tel" placeholder="5 gal" ng-model="startingWater">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label"><b>Pounds of Grain Required</b></span>
            <input type="tel" placeholder="10 lbs" ng-model="lbsOfGrain">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label"><b>Initial Temperature of Dry Grain</b></span>
            <input type="tel" placeholder="70 &deg; F" ng-model="grainTemp">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label"><b>Target Temperature of Mash</b></span>
            <input type="tel" placeholder="155 &deg; F" ng-model="targetTemp">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-output">
            <span class="text"><b>Required Infusion Water Temperature</b></span>
            <span class="result" placeholder="Ex. 170 &deg; F"><b>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp{{iStrikeResult}} &deg; F</b></span>
        </label>
        <p></p>

        <button class="button icon ion-beer" ng-click="iniStrikeCalc()">&nbsp Calculate</button>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any calculation has nothing to do with angular or ionic, it is native javascript. Please create demo that replicates problem. Also why are you assigning string values for variables that should be numeric?

Comment: @charlietfl is right, those values should be a Number, not a string. That could potentially cause issues

Comment: In particular, if the value you are using for `targetTemp` is actually `"155"` then Javascript will just do string concatenation with the final result and `8.5` would become `"8.5155"` instead of `163.5`.

Comment: Could you also provide the html you're using please?

Comment: All your HTML inputs are `<input type="tel">` ... it might work better if you change that to `<input type="number">` and remove your initialization code that sets the values to empty strings.

Comment: convert all variables to number within calcs, should work fine

Comment: @charlietfl can you elaborate on this a bit more for me?  How would that look in the .js file?  I understand "" means string (I never gave it much thought at the time).  Should I do something like <br>$scope.startingWater = startingWater;</br>

Comment: `<input type="text">` values are strings. So you are likely binding to them using `ng-model` and thus they are string values. Read up on the many many ways to convert string to number in javascript and do each one before using in calculations

Comment: @SunilD.  Thanks for the insight.  I changed "tel" to "number" and that helped with a portion of the problem.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your suggestions.  I deleted the portion of code where I initialized the variables as a string.  I'll post code below.  I'm still a rookie at this coding stuff.  Do you have any advice for me as I work along at this?  I'm a school teacher by profession but want to someday change the world and I feel that the only way for me to do this is to become a better programmer.  I made a simple app for my students already.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: One simple way is put a plus sign before string . `+"33"` becomes number `33`. But also need to make sure there are no invalid letters in value when doing it or will be `NaN` . Understand re-inventing yourself, I did same thing and am 100% self taught web dev

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your insights.  I'll post the code then explain. 


HTML changes

```
<div class="list card">
            <div class="item stable-bg">
                <h2 align="center">Initial Strike Water Calculator</h2>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-body" align="left" ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
                <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label"><b>Initial Gallons of Water</b></span>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="5 gal" ng-model="startingWater">
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label"><b>Pounds of Grain Required</b></span>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="10 lbs" ng-model="lbsOfGrain">
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label"><b>Initial Temperature of Dry Grain</b></span>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="70 &deg; F" ng-model="grainTemp">
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label"><b>Target Temperature of Mash</b></span>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="155 &deg; F" ng-model="targetTemp">
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-output">
                        <span class="text"><b>Required Infusion Water Temperature</b></span>
                        <span class="result" placeholder="Ex. 170 &deg; F"><b>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp{{iStrikeResult}} &deg; F</b></span>
                    </label>
                    <p></p>

                        <button class="button icon ion-beer" ng-click="iniStrikeCalc()">&nbsp Calculate</button>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

.js changes

```
  //Initial Strike Water Requirements

  $scope.iniStrikeCalc = function(){
    $scope.startingWaterQt = $scope.startingWater*4;
    $scope.r = $scope.startingWaterQt/$scope.lbsOfGrain;
    $scope.rby2 = .2/$scope.r;
    $scope.iStrikeResult = ((($scope.targetTemp - $scope.grainTemp)*($scope.rby2)) + $scope.targetTemp);
```

What I did was change all "tel" values from the HTML input tag from type="tel" to type ="number".  I dont know why but this helped make all the complex math I've had throughout my code in other functions work better.  Basic algebra was not an issue but with compound fractions, some functions did not work well.


Another thing that I did was to delete all variables which were initialized to a "" value in my .js file.  I was wanting to declare the variable before I used it but I believe that this is done when the function is called.  I had a few misbehaving functions in my program and after trying these two changes in my trouble areas, things work like a charm.


Thank you all very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt when performing arithmetic operation like this.

```
$scope.total += parseInt(actual_data);
```